# GUI Button display totals C#

Tags: c#, user-interface, button

I am very new to coding, so this is likely a simple answer. I am trying to get my GUI button in C# to display the total of an arithmetic function I wrote. For example:

```
int totalGold = goldOnHand + earnedGold;
```

I have tried to display the totalGold as such in a text box name TxtGold:

```
private void BtnSplit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TxtGold.Text = "totalGold";
}
```

The text box only displays: totalGold
How do I get the textbox to display the integer that represents the total amount of gold instead of the phrase totalGold?
Thanks for any help from someone willing to give a hand to a noob!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TxtGold.Text = "totalGold";` will print the string "totalGold" in your text box. If you need to print the integer value assigned to variable totalGold you have to print it as shown below

```
TxtGold.Text = totalGold.ToString();//that is, avoid the double quotes
```

the full code might be as follows

```
private void BtnSplit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  int totalGold = goldOnHand + earnedGold;
    TxtGold.Text = totalGold.ToString();
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will get an exception because `Text` must be a string, not an integer.

Answer (score 4):

In this code

```
int totalGold = goldOnHand + earnedGold;
```

You created a variable called `totalGold`. And you want to display it in a text box. That's so far so good. But when you try to set the text, things went wrong. You set the text of the text box to `"totalGold"`.

In C#, `""` means a *string literal*. Its value is "What you see is what you get". So when you say `"totalGold"`, it displays the word totalGold. What you need to do is to remove the `""` so that `totalGold` turns into a variable.

```
TxtGold.Text = totalGold;
```

But `totalGold` is an integer! you can only set the text of a text box using a string! How to convert from an integer to a string? Simple, use the `ToString()` method!

```
TxtGold.Text = totalGold.ToString();
```

Comment: Detailed and logical: +1

Comment: Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 2):

Turn it into a string using the [`ToString()` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t7dwaa5(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TxtGold.Text = totalGold.ToString();
```

**WHY:**

What you were doing is setting the text of the button to a [string literal](http://www.dotnetperls.com/string-literal), not the value of the variable.

Additionally, you cannot set `TxtGold.Text` to the integer, because it is a string property (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.text(v=vs.110).aspx)). Therefore, you have to do a `ToString()` to convert the integer to a string.